# Put Button and Seek Bar in Container

Tags: android, android-layout, button, constraints, seekbar

I'm trying to get my seek-bar and my 2 buttons within the space thats under the search box. (I drew in black where I'm trying to place the seekbar & button) I attached an image to better explain what I would like my layout to look like. I tried changing to a frame-layout and adding constraints but I can't figure what I'm doing wrong. Each time I add constraints and move one 1 button everything else groups together in the top left corner. Is their a specific layout I should be using in order to get my seek bar in the space and my 2 button on the bottom right corner? [image]Here is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/searchEditText"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/searchButton"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/searchButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:text="@string/form_search_button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/searchButton"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/stopButton"
            android:layout_width="97dp"
            android:layout_height="38dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="18dp"
            android:hint="Stop"
            android:text="@string/stop"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/pauseButton"
            android:layout_width="85dp"
            android:layout_height="34dp"
            android:hint="pause"
            android:text="@string/pause" />

        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/seekBar"
            android:layout_width="378dp"
            android:layout_height="12dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="123dp" />
    </FrameLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Seekbar position on top? or with the 2 buttons at the bottom right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using a `ConstraintLayout` replacing your `FrameLayout`,

Constraint `Seekbar`:

- top to top of parent
- end to end of parent

Then use a `LinearLayout` to hold two buttons.

Then constraint the `LinearLayout` :

- bottom to bottom of parent
- end to end of parent

Doing this will make the seekbar stay on top right and buttons stay at bottom right corner.

Answer (score 0):

I guess by under the search box, you mean SeekBar & 2 Buttons in same line but I couldnt understand your drawing.

You should be using LinearLayout for this.

1) If You want all 3 in same line then you should do like this

```
<LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatSeekBar
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

2) If you want seek bar in one line and 2 buttons below that seekbar but in one line then

```
<LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatSeekBar
            android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical">

        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

You may give specific width to buttons if it is possible. Please ignore the AppCompatSeekBar & Material Button. It will work on SeekBar & Button in same way.

You may also put 2 buttons at the bottom of the screen if you need then the parent of SeekBar & LinearLayout(Consist of 2 Buttons) should be Relative Layout with height match parent and LinearLayout(Consist of 2 Buttons) should align parent bottom.

UPDATE:

Here just like you wanted. It might slightly different but you can modify it now.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/containerSearch"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_margin="16dp">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/searchEditText"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/searchButton"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/searchButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="5"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/containerSearch"
        android:layout_margin="16dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/seekBar"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="12dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="end"
        android:layout_margin="24dp"
        android:weightSum="5"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="2"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="16dp">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/pauseButton"
                android:text="PAUSE"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:hint="pause" 
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/stopButton"
                android:text="STOP"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="40dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Now, in case you need to show list or other controls between your SeekBar and bottom Buttons then these two need to be inside single LinearLayout where SeekBar container is first child and your list is second and the bottom buttons are in third child. or you can keep botttom buttons on BottomBar which stays on top.

Comment: I wanted the two buttons in the bottom right next to each other side by side not in the place they are now and the seek bar to be in the same space as the buttons but right understand the search box  and have it centered, sorry if the image was confusing. The drawing was meant to show where I wanted things vs where they are now. @xSHERU

Comment: I tried Linear Layout and it still does not work for me @xSHERU

Comment: Ok, SeekBar needs to align at the bottom of search box right but in right side like the buttons at bottom?

Comment: @csscoder Check the 'UPDATE'. It should be close to what you needed. Understand the LinearLayout and usage of weights and you can modify it as per your requirement.

Comment: @csscoder tools:context=".MainActivity" I have removed this, since I didnt need it on my machine. Add it. Also check if any resources you were using before. Change those like before and it will work fine.